# React native navigation shows White screen

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am getting a white screen upon compilation using react-native navigation, Pls why is this so? I do not seem to get any Error codes, nothing, i just see a white screen. Why is this so? My codes Looks like this and shows I do not seem to have any errors so far.

Here is what the Error seems to look like 
[image: Error-Drawer.png]

As You can see it looks and compiles successfully but when i try to have a look to see what i have Done so far, i get a pure white screen

My code looks thus :

**App.js**

```
//import liraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import DrawerNavigator from './components/ControlPage';

// create a component
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DrawerNavigator/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// define your styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },
});

//make this component available to the app
export default App;
```

**ControlPage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';

import { createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer'; 
import Main from './Main';
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
Home : {screen : Main},
Screen1:{screen : Screen1},
Screen2:{screen : Screen2},
 },
{
   InitialRouteName : 'Home',
   drawerWidth : 300,
   drawerPosition: 'left'
}
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

// create a component
class DrawerNavigator extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <AppContainer/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

// define your styles 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
},
text:{
    fontSize: 26,
    color: 'purple'
},

touchableHighlight: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderRadius : 50,
    alignItems : 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 10,
    top : 10
},

open: {
    color : 'white',
    fontSize : 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
},

});

//make this component available to the app
export default DrawerNavigator;
```

**Main.js**

```
//import liraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';

// create a component
class Main extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'Home',
        drawerIcon : () =>(
            <Image source ={require('../icons/home.png')}/>
        ),
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())} style={styles.touchableHighlight} underlayColor={'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'}>
            <Text style={styles.open}>OPEN</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <Text style={styles.text}> Welcome to Home Screen </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

// define your styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFF',
    },

    text:{
    fontSize: 26,
    color: 'purple'
},
});

//make this component available to the app
export default Main;
```

Other screens are just to display and hide the Drawer. 
Pls i need guidance am i missing anything?

Answer (score 8):

This is a common issue showing up when `alignItems: 'center'` is applied to the container of a navigator.
Remove it from `App.js` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

After removing alignItems: 'center' from app.js file, it worked. For some reason, react native does not show any error msg instead of white screen

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure you aren't wrapping your NavigationContainer with a SafeAreaView.

Answer (score 1):

when follow doc
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/2.1.1/#js

```
export default function App() {
  return <GestureHandlerRootView>{/* content */}</GestureHandlerRootView>;
}
```

like docs content `you will need to pass { flex: 1 }`. just pass style to it.

(actually I use react-native-reanimated@3, not need to use GestureHandlerRootView)

Answer (score -4):

I got it to work now , i just made few Adjustments and changed few Links and all worked fine here. No more White screens.

Comment: How did you fix it? Maybe someone can benefit from your solution