# Blank screen when I put Drawer Navigator as the main navigator in index.tsx

Tags: react-native, expo, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation

If I put Drawer Navigator in index.tsx I only get a blank screen.

Tried wrapping NavigationContainer in index.tsx in a View with flex: 1 but it didn't work.
Also I don't have alignItems: 'center' in App.tsx to remove as this answer suggests. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62647417/13117660)

index.tsx:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const store = configureStore({});

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <DatabaseConnectionProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props: any) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />} screenOptions={{
              headerTitle: () => <Image source={require('../assets/logo_navbar.jpg')} style={{
                width: 120,
                height: 40,
                alignContent: 'center'
              }} />,
              headerTitleAlign: 'center',
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: Colors.RED,
              }
            }} >
              <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen}></Drawer.Screen>
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </DatabaseConnectionProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

CustomDrawerContent.tsx:

```
const CustomDrawerContent: FC = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.RED }}>
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} style={styles.drawerContent2}>
        <View style={styles.drawerContent}>
          <Drawer.Section style={styles.drawerSection}>
            <DrawerItem
              labelStyle={{ color: Colors.WHITE, fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 20 }}
              label={"Home"}
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate("Home");
              }}
            />
            <DrawerItem
              labelStyle={{ color: Colors.WHITE, fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 20 }}
              label={"About us"}
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate("AboutUs");
              }}
            />
            <DrawerItem
              labelStyle={{ color: Colors.WHITE, fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 20 }}
              label={"Impresum"}
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate("Impresum");
              }}
            />
            <DrawerItem
              labelStyle={{ color: Colors.WHITE, fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 20 }}
              label={"Contact"}
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate("Contact");
              }}
            />
          </Drawer.Section>
        </View>
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CustomDrawerContent;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  drawerContent: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.RED,
  },
  drawerContent2: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  labels: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  userInfoSection: {
    paddingLeft: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginTop: 3,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  caption: {
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 14,
  },
  row: {
    marginTop: 20,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  section: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginRight: 15,
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginRight: 3,
  },
  drawerSection: {
    marginTop: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    backgroundColor: Colors.RED,
  },
});
```

Edit:

Also when I use the Drawer Navigator like this in index.tsx it also shows just blank screen

```
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <DatabaseConnectionProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator>
              <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen}></Drawer.Screen>
              <Drawer.Screen name='About' component={AboutUsScreen}></Drawer.Screen>
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </DatabaseConnectionProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
```

When I put a breakpoint on the return of HomeScreen component it gets hit only the first time the app loads, but nothing renders on screen. If I reload the app than the HomeScreen breakpoint is not hit. I have to stop the server and run the app again every time. But the blank screen is always there.

If I change the Drawer Navigatior to Stack Navigatior than everything works. But I need the Drawer Navigator to be the main navigator.

I am using expo, @react-navigation/drawer 6.3.0 and @react-navigation/native 6.0.8

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/70666789/10657559

Comment: Well I don't have a View around the Navigator. Only around the drawerContent. But I have tried it and the blank screen is still there

Comment: you dont have to use the DrawerNavigation as the main navigator. can use it deep inside stackNavigator as well and home will be on the drawernavigation

Answer (score 1):

So I found out what wasn't working. My debbuger was on and it was causing problems as explained here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10253

I am debugging in VS code, not in Chrome Debugger but still when I turn off debugging it works. If the debugger is on you have to put

```
useLegacyImplementation={false}
```

as a prop in Drawer.Navigator. It is little laggy but works.

I am using react-native-reanimated 2.4.0